# Scala - mixing in a trait with its imports (inheriting imports)

Tags: scala, inheritance, import

I have the following code:

```
trait A {
  import org.somepackage.C._
}

class B extends A {
  def getValue = value
                 ^^^^^
}

object C {
  var value = 5
}
```

The value in class `B` is not visible what means that the inherent import of class `A` was not inherited by `B`, although the `value` is perfectly visible inside `A`. How to achieve the effect of also inheriting imports so I could avoid explicitly importing same things in multiple classes where trait `A` mixes in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Scala, how do I pass import statements through to subclasses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252126/in-scala-how-do-i-pass-import-statements-through-to-subclasses)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Imports not being a first class entity do not exhibit the behavior you are expecting. You can instead restructure your design thusly to achieve something close:

```
trait A with C {

}

class B extends A {
  def getValue = value // Now this will work.
}

trait C {
  var value = 5
}

object C extends C
```

This idiom is used in Scalaz 6 to tax users with as few imports as possible.

Comment: This appears to only work if `C` is a trait. What if `C` is something else (in my case, `C` is a method)? When I try to use this pattern, it simply says `Cannot resolve symbol C` (where `C` is the name of the method I would otherwise be importing via `com.xyz.C`).

Comment: Furthermore, what if I wanted to include everything, as in `com.xyz._`?

Comment: For both of the above, you need to move the implementation to a trait, then have an object that simply extends the trait, like in the answer.  Traits can be extended to do the "mixing in", objects can't.  To include everything, like com.xyz._ you need to implement com.xyz via a package object - with the package object similarly implemented by extending a trait that has all the actual implementations.  Then, you can use that trait to also "mix in" elsewhere.